# Setting store scope when running script via cron

Tags: magento2, multistore, cron

I am **sending emails** with a script executed on **cron** and have attempted to set the **current store** with:

```
$stores = $this->_storeRepository->getList();
foreach ($stores as $store) {
    $this->storeManager->setCurrentStore($store["store_id"]);
    ...
```

This however is not setting the correct **store email** and **name** for below code:

```
$storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE; 
$sender = [
                'name' => $this->scopeConfig->getValue('trans_email/ident_sales/name', $storeScope),
                'email' => $this->scopeConfig->getValue('trans_email/ident_sales/email', $storeScope)
            ];
```

If there a way to **set the store** correctly with script run via **cron** or another way to grab these values by `store_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a third parameter to the `getValue` method for Store seemed to work for me. This seems to be how `getStoresConfigByPath($path)` within  **`Magento\Store\Model\StoresConfig`** achieves this:

```
$value = $this->_config->getValue($path, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $store->getCode());
```

My code now looks like below:

```
$storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE; 

$sender = [
                'name' => $this->scopeConfig->getValue('trans_email/ident_sales/name', $storeScope, $store["store_id"]),
                'email' => $this->scopeConfig->getValue('trans_email/ident_sales/email', $storeScope, $store["store_id"])
            ];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending email to customers then you can get **Store Id** from `customer_entity` table or if you send using order table then by **`sales_order`** table.

**Set:** `$storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORES;`

Comment: I have the ID of the store and is set as per in my question. The only difference i can see here is SCOPE_STORES being used rather than SCOPE_STORE however either way I seem to be getting the email for the default store.

Comment: How you get STORE ID in cron? because in Cron default store id will be 0 means admin store id. I saw you are using: **setCurrentStore** function why you need it? to get product image or something.

Comment: Im just doing it for each store so grab each store and loop checking config for that store and if enabled run the code. I am not using that set current store anymore it didn't seem to work for me.